# Why wont postgresql use index for the query?

Tags: postgresql

I have this small query

```
select t.* from table1 t
left join table2 t2 on t2.related_uuid = t.uuid and t2.inventoried is true
where t2.org like 'org%' or t.org like 'org%'
```

Both table1 and table2 have few thousand rows (< 5000). But this query takes ~6 seconds to run. Given that table2.inventoried is true is common in many queries, i thought maybe i should add a partial index over inventoried column with condition inventoried is true could improve performance. Table2 is 90% inventoried is false and 10% inventoried is true.  But when looking at explain it does not use the index.

Additionally Table2 contains a column type which can have values: table1, table3, table4. So i could also go with index over it and add an additional condition to the join where t2.type = 'table1'. But this also goes unused.

Index creation queries

```
create index idx on table2(inventoried) where inventoried is true
create index idx2 on table2(type) where type = 'table1'
```

I think im doing something wrong, but i just cant quite put my finger on it.

EDIT:
Execution plan without indexes

```
"Hash Right Join  (cost=227.83..361.03 rows=3024 width=331) (actual time=0.912..2.242 rows=982 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: (t2.related_uuid = t.uuid)"
"  Filter: ((t2.org ~ 'St%'::text) OR (t.org ~ 'St%'::text))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 2168"
"  Buffers: shared hit=274"
"  ->  Seq Scan on table2 t2  (cost=0.00..129.85 rows=1276 width=58) (actual time=0.007..0.300 rows=1265 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (inventoried IS TRUE)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 11"
"        Buffers: shared hit=117"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=188.48..188.48 rows=3148 width=331) (actual time=0.893..0.893 rows=3150 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1104kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=157"
"        ->  Seq Scan on table1 t  (cost=0.00..188.48 rows=3148 width=331) (actual time=0.004..0.423 rows=3150 loops=1)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=157"
"Planning Time: 0.153 ms"
"Execution Time: 2.315 ms"
```

Comment: Or you are creating index that does no match you select criterion or postgres thinks that a full scan query is best. please provide `explain` or a `explain analyze` - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html

Comment: It must take some very weird data distribution, or spectacularly awful hardware, for that to take 6 seconds even with no indexes.

Comment: Cant be hardware as the DB is in cloud. Might be data distribution, as all the devs on the project know our data model is grabage, but we cant make it bettter because we have no analysis document so we trying to make the best out of the bad situation. Or the 6s runtime can be attributed to pgadmin.

Comment: Your query is malformed. The outer join is sliently converted into an inner join by the predicate `t2.org like 'org%' or t.org like 'org%'`. Please fix the query so we can help you.

Comment: @theimpaler Well i think there is some gap in my knowledge, as i do not know how it is malformed and how to fix it.

Comment: @LukStorms would it be ok then if i moved the 't2.org like 'org%'' into the 'on' clause and inside 'where' i just check if t2.uuid is not null or something?

Comment: The query takes less than 3 **milli**seconds, not 6 seconds.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name WHen i run query tself it takes 5-6 seconds. If i run it with explain it takes 600ms. I guess some of the time spent can be placed under network connection.

Comment: Then there is a huge lag in sending the result from the server to your application or the tool you use to run the statement. Which seems rather strange as the query only returns 982 rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well im using PGadmin to connect to DB in cloud... COuld be pgAdmin issue maybe then?

Comment: @MarkoTaht Remove the `left` clause in the join, for the query to make sense.

Comment: @TheImpaler removing left would change the outcome.

Comment: @MarkoTaht No, it won't. The query is already performing an inner join, even if you are writing an outer join. That's the problem [and confusion].

Comment: @TheImpaler then i would say the query is wrong. Would adding t2.id is null int owhere clause and moving t2.org like 'org%' into join clause make it work properly? Cause there might be no entries in table2 for a row in table 1 but table1 might still have a value of org like 'org%'

Comment: @MarkoTaht That would make sense. Alternatively you can place the predicate in the `ON` clause, instead of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be hard to get a usable index for an OR which draws from two different tables.  You could instead write it as a union:

```
select t.* from table1 t where t.org like 'org%'
union [all?]
select t.* from table1 t join table2 t2 on t2.related_uuid = t.uuid where  t2.inventoried is true and t2.org like 'org%'
```

But, will this deal with duplicate rows in a manner you find acceptable?  Only you can answer that.

Comment: Im gona try next time i have access to the DB.